# Configuring the stopping of TeamCity build job

Tags: teamcity, stoppropagation

I was wondering if it is somehow possible to setup the TC not to send kill -9 signal when the build process is stopped. Is it configurable?

Thanks

Comment: How would you like TeamCity to behave instead, a different signal or no signal at all? What problem are you trying to solve/why do you want to do that, maybe there is an alternative?

Comment: Already resolved. POssible to dedine a SIGTERM signal.